# Find another way to get a.href of li elment with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, children, attr

I have a HTML bellow:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#doc-new">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#doc-fav">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#doc-read">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to get **href** of `<a>` element of `<li>` have 'active' class

I have a query like that:

```
//get current tab
$('ul.tabs li > a').click(function () {

    var t = $('ul.tabs li:[class="active"]').next().children().attr('href'); 
    alert(t);
});
```

It's worked however I want to find another query more better than mine.

Thanks !

Comment: I don't know why we need next() method here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this

```
var t =  $('ul.tabs li.active a').attr('href'); 
alert(t);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VFFmH/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the class in the selector

```
var t = $('ul.tabs li.active a').attr('href');
```

The jQuery API selectors section is very informative with examples also. This is not a hard selector to figure out

API reference:  http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".tabs li").find(".active").next().attr("href");
```

Answer (score 0):

check this..

```
 //get current tab
    $('ul.tabs li > a').click(function () {

        var t = $('ul.tabs li:[class="active"]').find("a").attr('href'); 
        alert(t);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the 'HREF' for the 'a' that is clicked.

You can do this

```
$('ul.tabs li > a').click(function () {

alert($(this).attr('href'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li a.active").attr("href");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var href = $("ul.tabs").find("li.active").find("a").attr("href");
alert(href);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('ul.tabs li > a').click(function () {
   if($(this).parent().hasClass("active")){
      alert(this.href);
   }
});
```